# Javascript adding events to object properties on runtime

Tags: javascript, events, properties, get, set

Let's say that we have an already existing code that has this object:

```
function randomObject(id){
this.id = id;
}
```

An easy way to add events to e.g. id property would be like this:

```
function myObject(_id){
    this._id = _id;
    this.id = function(Id){
        //get
        if(Id === undefined){
          fireGetEvent();
          return this._id;
        }
        //or set
        fireSetEvent();
        this._id = Id;
    }
```

However, there is a major problem with this. This way it's impossible to add events to existing objects, because now properties have to be set or get this way:

```
anObject.id(5); //set
alert(anObject.id()); //get
```

And this will stop working:

```
anObject.id = 5; //set
alert(anObject.id); //get
```

*Is there any way to add custom get and set to object properties **so that original code will still work?***

```
//#can't touch this:
function randomObject(id){
this.id = id;
}
//Call this on property change
function callMeMaybe(num){
alert("You're a genius! Here's your lucky number: " + num);
}
var anObject = new randomObject(5);
//#

//##Do whatever you like to solve this puzzle and make setting id on "anObject" call "callMeMaybe"
// Your code here
//##

//###Can't touch this:
anObject.id = 42; //Here "callMeMaybe" should be fired
alert(anObject.id); //Here id should be displayed properly
//###
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript provides a built-in way to add getters and setters.  This may or may not be compatible with your supported browser requirements.

Here's a page that describes the compatibility.  http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html

```
var o = {
    id: null
};

Object.defineProperty(o, "id", {
    get: function () {
        console.log('getter called');
        return this.idPropValue;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        console.log('setter called with value: ' + value);
        this.idPropValue = value;
    }
});

o.id = 123;
var id = o.id;
alert(id);
```